# how do I write regex to stop at a particular string?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I'm trying to write a parser to divide up a .txt file full of data according to authors, titles, and reviews. i've hit a block and don't know what to do next. I'm having problems with just one line of code, the regex code, in the cell that sez # Now separate reviews from titles

the code misses apostrophes (\'). and when i try to use a caret ^ to block the last stretch, i get an empty set. i include a bit if the source text below so you can see the mess I'm trying to parse. it's tricky! a title will flow directly into the name of a journal, like Choice. so i'm trying to separate by cutting off the words that immediately precede a \s-\s pattern.

Here's the code:

```
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
    content = [x.strip() for x in content]
    content = " ".join(content)

# Get all authors
pattern = r"[A-Z\-]{2,}[\,]+\s[A-Za-z\s\,\(\)\.]+\s[\-\*\•\.\■ ]{1}"
authors = re.findall(pattern, content)

# Now replace all found authors with XXX_XXX
if re.search(pattern, content):
    r = re.compile(pattern)
    content2 = r.sub(r'XXX_XXX', content)

# Now get all the content for each author
content3 = content2.split('XXX_XXX')
bib = content3[1:]

# Now separate reviews from titles
**pattern2 = r"[A-Z][a-z][\w\'\-\:\;\s\(\)]+\w+\s\-\s"**
bib2 = "".join(bib)
titles = re.findall(pattern2, bib2)
```

It's this line, pattern2, that I can't get to work. Source code below:

```
MA, Huan • The Overall Survey Of The Ocean’s Shores 1433
Choice - v8 - 0 ’71 - pl074 MA, Huan • Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan AHR - v76 - D ’71 - pl578 GJ - vl37 - Je ’71 - p213 JAS - v31 - N ’71 - pl81 TLS - Je 16 ’72 - p681 MA, Laurence J C - Commercial Development And Urban Change In Sung China 960-1279
JAS - v31 - Ag ’72 - p928 Pac A - v45 - Summer ’72 - p285 MA, Laurence J C - The Environment JAS - v42 - N ’82 - pl39 MA, Laurence J C - Urban Development In Modern China
Choice - vl9 - Ja ’82 - p696 JAS - v42 - N 82 - pl39 MA, Nancy Chih - Cook Chinese AB - v45 - My 25 ’70 - pl786 PW - vl97 - Mr 23 ’70 - p38 MA, Nancy Chih • Don’t Lick The Chopsticks CSM - v66 - Ja 10 ’74 - pF2 LJ - v99 - Mr 15 ’74 - p757 MA, Nancy Chih - Mrs. Ma’s Japanese Cooking
VQR - v58 - Spring ’82 - p68 MA, Tsu Sheng - Microscale Manipulations In Chemistry
Choice-vl3-N ’76 -pi 164 MA, Tsu Sheng - Organic Functional Group Analysis By Gas Chromatography Choice - vl3 - F ’77 - pl624 r MA, Wei-Yi - A Bibliography Of Chinese-Language Materials On The People's Communes ARBA - vl5 - '84 - p320
Pac A - v56 - Winter ’83 - p796 MA, Wook - Seoul Ro Kanun Kil BL - v78 - 0 15 '81 - p294 y MA, Y W - Traditional Chinese Stories ANQ - vl8 - 0 ’79 - p30 BF - v4 - Ap 40 '79 - p575 Choice -vl5-Ja ’79 -pl528 HR-v32-Spring'79-pl23 JAS - v38 - Ag '79 - p773 Kliatt - vl3 • Winter '79 - p26 WIT - v53 - Summer '79 - p555 MA, Yun • Shih Ching T'ao Hsing BL - v68 - Ap 1 '72 - p651 MA BRICALL, Josep - Politica Economica De La Generalitat 1936-1939. Vol. 1 WP - v25 - O '72 - pl55 MA COY, Ramelle • Short-Time Compensation
Choice - v21 - Jl '84 - pl648 Econ Bks - vll - S ’84 - p62 c MA De - The Cowherd And The Weaving Maid
Cur R - v20 - S '81 -p325 c MA De - Crickets
Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c MA De - School-Master Dongguo Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 c MA De - Thrice Borrowing The Plantain Fan CurR- v20-S ’81 -p325 c MA De - The Wonderful Gourds Cur R - v20 - S '81 - p325 MAACK, Berthold - Preussen JMH - v55 - Mr '83 - p71 r MAACK, Mary N - Libraries In Senegal ARBA - vl3 - '82 - pi53 CRL - v45 - Mr '84-pl52 JAL - v7 - S '81 - p244 JLH - vl9 - Spring ’84 - p315 LJ - vl07 - My 1 ’82 - p865 LQ - v52 - Ap '82-pl75 MAACK, Reinhard • Kontinentaldrift Und Geologie Des Sudatlantischen Ozeans GJ - vl36 - Mr '70 - pl38 MAAG, Russell C - Observe And Understand The Sun
S&T - v54 - S ’77 - p221 MAAG, Victor - Hiob
Rel St Rev - vlO - Ap '84 - pi 75 MAAILMA Katettu Poyta
WIT - vS8 • Winter '84 - pi 36 MAALOE, Ole - Control Of Macromolecular Synthesis
Choice - v3 - 0 '66 - p676 Sci - vl54 - D 2 '66 - pll59 MAALOUF, Amin • The Crusades Through Arab Eyes
TLS -N 16 ’84 -pi300 c MAAR, Len - Out-Of-Sight Games CBRS - v9 - F ’81 - p57 SLJ-v27 - Mr ’81 -pl48 p MAARAV
Choice - vl6 - D '79 - pl280 MAAREK, Gerard • Introduction Au Capital De Karl Marx
JEL - vl7 - Mr ’79 - p92 MAAS, Audrey Gellen • Wait Till The Sun Shines, Nellie
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve, maybe we can help in the first place?

Comment: Did you extract the data from a web page? Maybe the original page structure would help in sorting it out.

Comment: So the .txt file is an index of book reviews. I need to clean up the data, separating it into three columns in a dataframe: author, title, reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can just match the record, and it's parts directly instead of doing
split, sub's and other stuff.

In the end, you're just doing the same thing.

I know it's hard. It's like a dog with a bone so big it doesn't know how to
approach it.

I've tried to break up the parts a little better.

Group 1 contains the author.
Group 2 contains the title.
Group 3 contains misc stuff (the remaining stuff up to the next author).

All I've done is to make every record of the sample match correctly.
This usually covers all the bases if the sample is diverse enough.

If you find special cases, you'll have to horn it into the code.

> A thing to note - The *Misc* part uses a negative assertion to test each
>   character up until the next *Author*.
>   If you make a change to the author part, you have to copy that change to
>   this assertion.

Good Luck!!

`(?s)([A-Z-]{2,},*\s(?:[A-Za-z\s,().]|[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z])+)\s[-*•.■ ]\s*(?:([A-Z](?:(?!\s+-|\s+Choice\s*-).)*?\w)(?:\s+-\s*|\s+(?=Choice\s*-)|\s*$))?((?:(?![A-Z-]{2,},*\s(?:[A-Za-z\s,().]|[A-Za-z]-[A-Za-z])+\s[-*•.■ ]).)*)`

https://regex101.com/r/dg7hAB/1

[Formatted/Expanded/Explained](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 (?s)                          # Dot-all modifier

 (                             # (1 start), Required Author
      [A-Z-]{2,} 
      ,*                            # Optional comma's
      \s 
      (?:                           # Author characters, add more if needed
           [A-Za-z\s,().] 
        |  [A-Za-z] - [A-Za-z]           # allow hyphen between letters only
      )+
 )                             # (1 end)
 \s 
 [-*•.■ ]                      # Author ender
 \s* 
 (?:
      (                             # (2 start), Optional Title
           [A-Z]  
           (?:                           # Anything except title enders
                (?!
                     \s+ - 
                  |  \s+ Choice \s* - 
                )
                . 
           )*?
           \w                            # Should end with a word char
      )                             # (2 end)

      (?:                           # Title enders
           \s+ - \s* 
        |  \s+ 
           (?= Choice \s* - )            # Choice to be picked up by Misc Info
        |  \s* $ 
      )
 )?
 (                             # (3 start), Optional Misc Info
      (?:                           # Anything except start of new author
           (?!
                [A-Z-]{2,} 
                ,* 
                \s 
                (?:
                     [A-Za-z\s,().] 
                  |  [A-Za-z] - [A-Za-z] 
                )+
                \s 
                [-*•.■ ] 
           )
           . 
      )*
 )                             # (3 end)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! Okay, but I can't quite figure out how to use your regex code. When I slide the middle chunk—the bit that's meant to separate the titles—into my code, from above, I get a better result than I've gotten so far, but I still capture the word "Choice", which is the title of a journal, and I capture other all-caps code for journals, which aren't part of reviewed titles.

Comment: I.e. I get : 'Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan AHR'

Comment: The title is 'Ying-Yai Sheng-Lan'—'AHR' is the code for the title of a journal

Comment: This is when I plug the middle part of your code into 'pattern2' in my code. But it seems you're thinking of using the full regex code at once to separate the three parts. I wish I weren't so new at this, but I don't know how I'd do that.